# Can I secure my decryption key by using hardware backed credential storage in android

Tags: encryption, credentials, android-keystore

I want to secure my decryption key from hackers having root access. I read that hardware backed credential storage can be used to secure data even when devices is rooted. How much it is safe against emulators. Is it really safe.How to use this if it safe.

Comment: In any environment it is very difficult to impossible to secure data from the user. Ultimately the key must be in memory in order to use it and it is is in memory it is available to a sophisticated user/attacker.

Comment: Is the key supplies in the binary or created at runtime or obtained from a server?

Comment: Dear You may correct but. If it is android device. And key is created at runtime via very complex mechanism and with some data from server and just before decryption. How can one attacker do such thing in non rooted device.

Comment: The key is: "non rooted device" but an attacker will root the device. Security is about work factor, that is how hard it is to obtain the data. There is no 100% security level on a phone from the user so you need to evaluate the level of security you need. Define the attacker, skill level, amount of time and money he is willing to spend you want to defend against.Define the value of the data to you, your user and the attacker. Define how much you are willing to spend for security. Create security to meet these parameters. Mysterious "very complex mechanism" add little security.

Comment: Thanks Zaph. In rooted device my app will not work or starts any connection to server only after many system root boot checks. and no data will be available. But I know that attacker can create app like me to get data from my SSL server. Because of android apps has no certificates. But I have a idea to avoid such connections to my server. My app will have a complex code that is highly obfuscated by dexguard like programs. That will respond to servers checks which are meant to check if the app is real one or not. And an highly complex obfuscated app is not easy to rebuilt. What do you advice.